# HTML table childs filter

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a table that has 3 columns, the first one is customer name, then a button that triggers visibility toogle of a table in the third column and the third column contains a table that contains the user phone calls history.

I have succesfully created a filter for the first column an toggle the visibility of the second table. But when filtering and toggling at the same time, the rows of the second table doesn't show.

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2vorq2wp/1/#&togetherjs=Flwo3eRBKk) you can see an example of my code.

HTML basic code:

```
<table id='table1'>
  <tr>
    <th>titulo1</th>
    <th>titulo2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>texto1</td>
    <td>
      <table id='table2'>
        <tr>
          <th>titulo1</th>
          <th>titulo2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>data1</th>
          <th>data2</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS code:

```
function filtrar() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myFIlterInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("table1");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        } 
      }
    }
```

Comment: There's no `#myFIlterInput` in HTML. Also, there's no event and the act of toggling involves at least a 'click' event.

Comment: Sorry, you can just replace filter as `filter = 'texto1';`

Comment: Is there a button? You mentioned a button that should be in first column? Maybe you should: 1. State what you expect. 2. State what you are actually getting as a result.

Comment: not really a button, but a text in `<td>` that triggers an `onclick` event

Comment: If it's just text of a `<td>`, then reference the `<td>` and use the `.textContent` property. The `onclick` is actually a text that magically appears in a `<td>` or an `<input>`? An `<input>` would be easier to handle than a `<td>`.

Comment: I have updated the link to be more explicit with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in the filtering function, the cycle that hides `td` not only affects those who are on the same level but all those who are below the father.

I have added the second line

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
if(td.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id != 'table1'){continue;}
```

after getting the element to check its parent, if is not the one that I'm looking for, skip it.